# Make div disappear when list from drop down menu is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I made a dropdown menu when users are on iphone 6plus and lower and the drop down menu works fine but, when you click like "jobs or contact" it opens up but the drop down menu stays there. How do I make it "hide" after a list item is clicked in the iPhone 6plus width and lower. I have the drop down menu set with a toggle function so that might help understand it better.

Demo :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpyNwa

Html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 

             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magicstyle.css">

        </head>     
        <body>
            <!-- Section for Jobs Popup -->
            <div id="top-bar">
                  <a id="burger-nav"></a>
                    <ul id="nav-menu" class="blah">
                    <li id="job" class="testAgain">Job</li>
                    <li id="contact" class="testAgain">Contact</li>
                    <li id="press" class="testAgain">Press</li>
                    <li id="legal" class="testAgain">Legal</li>
                    <li id="support" class="testAgain">Support</li>


                </ul>
                    <!--<div id="nav-menu">
                    <span id="job">Jobs</span>
                    <span id="contact">Contact</span>
                    <span id="press">Press</span>
                    <span id="legal">Legal</span>
                    <span id="support">Support</span>

                    </div> -->


                </div>
                 <div id="job-popup">
            <div class="x-div1"><img class="x-icon1" id="fadeX1" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png" alt="Text alternative when image is not available"></div>
            <div id="job-content">

                <h1 id="jobWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Section for Contact Popup -->
            <div id="contact-popup">
            <div class="x-div2"><img class="x-icon2" id="fadeX2" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="contact-content">

                <h1 id="contactWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Section for Press Popu -->
             <div id="press-popup">
            <div class="x-div3"><img class="x-icon3" id="fadeX3" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="press-content">

                <h1 id="pressWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="legal-popup">
            <div class="x-div4"><img class="x-icon4" id="fadeX4" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="legal-content">

                <h1 id="legalWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="support-popup">
            <div class="x-div5"><img class="x-icon5" id="fadeX5" src="web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="support-content">

                <h1 id="supportWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>




            <div id="container">


                <div id="name-div">
                <h1 id="name">Open Touch</h1>
                </div>
                <ul class="bubbles">

            <li id="firstCircle"></li>
            <li id="secondCircle"></li>
            <li id="thirdCircle"></li>
            <li id="fourthCircle"></li>
            <li id="fifthCircle"></li>
            <li id="sixthCircle"></li>



            </ul>



            </div>



        </body>
```

Any help is appreciated

```
</html>
```

Comment: it doesn't look like a dropdown menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in your JS:

```
$('.testAgain').click(function(){ $('.blah').removeClass('open') })
```

Comment: Thank you very much